# Kotlin flow combine different types of flows (stateflow and flow, or sharedflow and flow)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

What happens when I combine a stateflow with a regular flow (like flow of 1,2,3)?
Official reference says "State flow never completes". So when does the combined flow complete? Never?